# My code keeps displaying an error when I run it on Python Tutor saying: "Too many to unpack". How do I fix this error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
big_str = "[41.386263640000003, -81.494450689999994]\t6\t2011-08-28 19:02:28\tyay. little league world series!\n[42.531041999999999, -82.90854831]\t6\t2011-08-28 19:02:29\ti'm at holiday inn express suites & hotel roseville mi (31900 little mack ave., at masonic blvd., roseville) \n[39.992309570000003, -75.131119729999995]\t6\t2011-08-28 19:02:29\t@_tweetthis what dorm r you in?\n[54.104106119999997, 28.336019929999999]\t6\t2011-08-28 19:02:29\t@andykozik круто !!!\n[25.787949600000001, -80.132949600000003]\t5\t2011-09-03 05:40:14\tpizza rustica #ftw"

# This breaks up a string of tweets into lists
def break_into_records(big_mess):
    rows = big_mess.split('\n')
    records = []
    for row in rows:
        records.append(row.split('\t'))
    for i in range(len(records)):
        records[i][0] = records[i][0].replace(' ','').strip('[]').split(',')
    return records

# This will loop over that list, and call a draw
# every time a word pops up
# as well as give you a word count
def count_words(word, data_structure):
    count = 0
    for loc, id, time, message in data_structure:
        if word in message:
            drop_pin(loc) # we pass cords to drop pin, no work to do
            count += message.count(word)
    return count

def drawGpsPoint(x):
  y = drop_pin(x)
  return y

def drop_pin(location):
    # this function needs to map the GPS cord to an x/y
    # so it can draw
    # but it has the GPS locs.
    lat, lon = location
    lat, lon = float(lat), float(lon)
    x = 500 - ((lat + 180) * 500.0/360)
    y = 500 - ((lon + 180) * 500.0/360)
    return lat, lon

a = break_into_records(big_str)
for x in a:
  drawGpsPoint(x)
  print("All Tweets Loaded")
  r = raw_input("Enter search word: ")
```

It shows the error every time it reaches the lat, lon in the drop_pin(location) function. Do I need to separate the variables first before running it through that line?

Comment: What do you get if you `print(location)` before the assignment?

Comment: Replace this ```lat, lon = location``` with this ```lat, lon = location[0]``` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @accdias That actually works...it fixed the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `break_into_records` function is splitting your string information into a `list` of elements, with the coordinates beeing the first element.

So to correct that error, you will need to replace `drawGpsPoint(x)` with:

```
drawGpsPoint(x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `break_into_records` isn't quite doing what you expect. The first time you call `drop_pin(location)`, your location is

```
[['41.386263640000003', '-81.494450689999994'], '6', '2011-08-28 19:02:28', 'yay. little league world series!']
```

Note that I determined this by printing out `location` before attempting to assign it.

The "too many values to unpack" error is caused by the fact that it doesn't make sense to try assign this to `lat, long`.

You probably mean to only return the first part of your `break_into_records` function, or perhaps you only mean to operate on the first parts of those strings.

Comment: I meant to put the first part, (the numbers in the bracket) to the lat, long. so the break_into_records function isn't working? Like it's not splitting them?